# Redis/Python: store and combine data by date

Tags: python, python-2.7, dataframe, redis

Objective (using Redis):

1. Cache data (as an object: example `dict` of `string/pandas dataframe`)
   by date
2. Retrieve data between date range (say 20101010 - 20151231)
3. Combine attributes of data between this date range (I'd like Redis
       to do this for me than combine it in python logic)

Example:

```
20101010: { "a" : dataframe_A1, "b" : "dataframe_B1 }, 
20101011: { "a" : dataframe_A2, "b" : "dataframe_B2 }
```

Output:

```
{"a" : dataframe_A1 concatenated with dataframe_A2, "b": dataframe_B1 concatenated with dataframe_B2}
```

One solution I've found is to use `ZADD/ZRANGEBYSCORE` technique, where I create an `index` on date in `YYYYMMDD` format, giving it a natural `set` ordering. This makes it trivial to retrieve data in a range (example: 20101010 - 20151231)
(using: https://redis.io/topics/indexes)

Is there a way retrieve data in a combined format from Redis efficiently (#3) - see my example output above.

What sequence of operations/commands would most efficiently get me this information?

Note:

- The dict above is just an example. It can be an object as well, with
  a way to combine its attributes.
- Dataframes can be stored using `to_msgpack` format into
  Redis([How to set/get pandas.DataFrame to/from redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37943778/how-to-set-get-pandas-dataframe-to-from-redis))

Thanks

Comment: I'm considering using Redis to store a time series as well, I'd use redis MULTI/EXEC or lua to do the ZRANGEBYSCORE which contain unique keys to HASH keys where you could do HGETALL to retrieve the object.  You could also store the object/dataframe as a JSON string, but that might be too much overhead depending on the complexity of the object and how efficient python's JSON parser is.

Comment: i implemented the above solution...but combining data from various dates in python is still slow (example: pandas.concat(..) for multiple dataframes)