# How to set/get pandas.DataFrame to/from Redis without msgpack or pyarrow

Tags: python, pandas, redis

I used to store and read pandas DataFrame to/from Redis using:

set:

```
redisConn.set("key", df.to_msgpack(compress='zlib'))
```

get:

```
pd.read_msgpack(redisConn.get("key"))
```

But `to_msgpack` is deprecated since pandas 0.25 to use `pyarrow` instead. Now `pyarrow` is deprecating serialization/deserialization in 2.0.0 https://arrow.apache.org/blog/2020/10/22/2.0.0-release/ (as indicated in [How to set/get pandas.DataFrame to/from Redis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37943778/how-to-set-get-pandas-dataframe-to-from-redis))

Anyone knows what the new recommended way is?

EDIT: I am using the current stable pandas version 1.2.4

Comment: Are you sure that mentioned pyarrow serialization deprecation is an issue? Docs just say that they deprecate python specific serialization/deserialization which was not compatible with the pyarrow standard one and ask to use "the right one", which is pyarrow.ipc, instead.